# How come delegate objects are allowed to call internal methods?

Tags: c#, delegates, clr, cil, reflection.emit

I can easily wrap a call to an internal method inside a delegate. The delegate can then call this method when I call `Invoke()`. However, the delegate is in the `mscorlib` assembly. Why can it call an internal method from my assembly?

Obviously, a delegate must be able to do this for C# to work properly. The question is not *why* it's allowed. It's *how*.

I assumed checking for visibility was a C# feature and that calling the method from CIL directly should just work. So I tried to just call that method from a dynamically defined type, thus using CIL directly and skipping C#. It failed miserably. Here's the code:

```
public static class InternalCall
{
    internal static void InternalMethod()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Successfully called an internal method from: " + typeof(InternalCall).Assembly.FullName);
    }

    public interface IMyAction
    {
        void MyInvoke();
    }

    private static IMyAction MakeMyAction()
    {
        var assembly = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Outside"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("Outside", false);
        var customType = module.DefineType("MyAction",
            TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit,
            typeof(object),
            new[] { typeof(IMyAction) });
        var method = customType.DefineMethod("MyInvoke",
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final);
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(InternalCall).GetMethod("InternalMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (IMyAction)customType.CreateType().GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
    }

    public static void RunTest()
    {
        var action = new Action(InternalMethod);
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling via action from assembly: " + action.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
        action.Invoke();

        var myAction = MakeMyAction();
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling via my type from assembly: " + myAction.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
        myAction.MyInvoke(); // MethodAccessException
    }
}
```

So, assuming delegates are still abiding by CIL rules (since that is what C# compiles to), what CIL mechanism are they using to call any method regardless of visibility?

Comment: Accessibility is checked when the delegate is *created*, not when it is invoked.  It would seriously suck boulders if it didn't work that way, event handlers should always be private.  This detail is otherwise highly invisible in C#, its syntax forces you to make the delegate's Target always equal to *this*.  So it is always accessible, regardless of the accessibility specifier.  But that is not a requirement in other languages, not in C++/CLI for example.

Comment: You've got two completely separate questions here, one asking how you're able to call a delegate pointing to a method that's not accessible to the code invoking a delegate, and another asking how to create a dynamic class that implements an interface and allows callers to get and use instances of it through the interface.  They should really be in separate questions, as they have entirely unrelated answers.

Comment: @Servy Changed the last line. Is this a bit better?

Comment: @HansPassant I understand that the accessibility is checked when the delegate is created, I just don't understand how this is accomplished. Also, what do you mean about *this*? The Target can be anything, including null, as is the case in code above. And in any case, the Target is just a reference stored in a delegate object, isn't it? The delegate is the one calling the target's method in the end.

Comment: Please explain your question better. It seems self-evident to me that delegates _must_ be able to refer to any method, including private or internal ones. After all, the vast majority of the time, the whole reason for using a delegate is to provide a way for one piece of code to call an otherwise inaccessible part of another piece of code. On the other hand, your second question about why you can't _compile_ code that attempts to access inaccessible members also seems self-evident: the whole point of the accessibility is to provide compile-time restrictions on access.

Comment: Bottom line: these are two completely independent features, and it doesn't make sense to ask why these two completely independent features have two completely independent behaviors. You might as well ask why you can add a number to an `int`, but you can't add a number to `bool`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, it is self-evident that the delegates must be able to refer to any method. I know how C# works. What I don't understand is how this is accomplished in the CIL that C# compiles to. I expected all those checks to be done at C# compile time, but it turns out they are done at CIL level as well. The emit part of the question was obviously not explained enough, but the point is I was trying to replicate the behavior of delegates to try and understand them. But it turns out you can't just call any method in CIL either. So how *do* the delegates call the methods at CIL level?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Edited the question, in hopes that what bothers me is a little bit clearer this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's insightful to see how a custom delegate looks in CIL:

```
.class auto ansi sealed MyDeleg extends [mscorlib]System.MulticastDelegate
{

.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor(object 'object', native int 'method') runtime managed
{
}

.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(class [mscorlib]System.AsyncCallback callback, object 'object') runtime managed
{
}

.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance int32  EndInvoke(class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult result) runtime managed
{
}

.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance int32  Invoke() runtime managed
{
}

}
```

That's it. The `runtime` attribute tells us that it's the runtime that provides the implementation for this method, not the code (`cil`). It's like p/invoke to the runtime. At this stage, there is no code-check, no verifier, no JIT. The execution is handled to the CLR to decide how to invoke the delegate, which then simply invokes it.

The execution is akin to the `calli` instruction, but that's not how these methods are implemented, although you can use it to simulate delegates fairly well. Why are there no visibility checks? Because it's the raw method pointer (from *GetFunctionPointer*) that is passed to the instruction, and obtaining its metadata may cause negative performace impact (or there may be no metadata at all). Of course doing any visibility checks is simply unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the basic mechanism behind delegates. Should have occurred to me before. They use indirect calls, i.e. the `calli` instruction in CIL, which doesn't seem to do visibility checks.

I'm still not sure what exactly they store and how they execute, but I am satisfied that hard-coding a method's function pointer into my emitted CIL can make this work so it illustrates the principle.

```
var toCallInfo = typeof(InternalCall).GetMethod("InternalMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
unsafe
{
    var functionPointer = toCallInfo.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
    if (sizeof(IntPtr) == 4)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, (int)functionPointer);
    else
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, (long)functionPointer);
}
il.EmitCalli(OpCodes.Calli, toCallInfo.CallingConvention, null, null, null);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Now creating the type and running it doesn't raise exceptions.

Comment: calli, as you can already tell, calls a function pointer.  This pointer points to the beginning of the method body of the method in question.  This instruction can be used to call any native code with a known signature, return type, and common calling convention.

Comment: A point to mention is that usually `calli` is used with a native int. The `conv.u` instruction should be used on the pointer.